# bracket not remove when with string formating why?

Tags: android

How to remove bracket around sstirng? I'm geting value from database save in arraystring when run database query its show bracket around value what do I do?
I want to remove bracket around stirng [AT]  how to do that?

```
static ArrayList<String> Meal_groupid = new ArrayList<String>();

String formatedString = "[AT]"
    .replace("[", "")   //remove the right bracket
    .replace("]", "");
        
Log.i("Formating Stirng",""+formatedString);
                 
Meal_groupid.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex("meal_group_id"))
        .replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));

Log.i("MEalGroup ID",""+Meal_groupid);
```

when see in logcat

> in     logcat  Formating Stirng    AT
>
> MEalGroup ID     [AT]

when I run query

```
Cursor mCursor =  db.selectQuery("
    SELECT m.menu_id, m.title AS menu_title
    FROM uss_school_to_menu sm
    LEFT JOIN uss_menu m on sm.menu_id = m.menu_id
    LEFT JOIN uss_school s on s.school_id = sm.school_id
    WHERE s.school_id = '"+ School_ID+"' AND sm.level_id = " +
    SchoolLevelId + " AND m.meal_group_code = '"+Meal_groupid.toString()+"'" );
```

in database it looks like this

```
SELECT m.menu_id, m.title AS menu_title
FROM uss_school_to_menu sm
LEFT JOIN uss_menu m on sm.menu_id = m.menu_id
LEFT JOIN uss_school s on s.school_id = sm.school_id
WHERE s.school_id = '147' AND sm.level_id = 1 AND m.meal_group_code = '[AT]'
```

I want to remove bracket around [AT]

Comment: Please edit your question and separate code from description,

Comment: in my arraylist  when save vlaue its show like this  Meal_groupid""[AT] how i will remove bracket

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `toString()` on your `ArrayList<String>` to get the string out of it, which won't work. If you call `toString()` on an `ArrayList<T>`, you typically get an output of

```
"[" + get(0).toString() + " " + get(1).toString() + " " + get(2).toString() + etc + "]"
```

You have only one element, so it ends up looking like brackets were added around your string.

Do you really need an array list here? If so, you need to replace `Meal_groupid.toString()` with `Meal_groupid.get(0)`, except 0 should be replaced with the index of whichever string in the list you need.

If you only need one string at a time, then avoid using the array list altogether, so you can directly plug the string into your database query.

You don't need `.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")`, because there are no brackets around your actual string.